# Jenkins : poll-mailbox-trigger-plugin doesn't work

Tags: email, jenkins, build, triggers

Before two weeks I setup build by email and was every things work fine 
but before two days I don't know why stop working
after check it's seem doesn't call 
"Poll an email inbox Schedule" at all, in log it is always like this "Polling has not run yet."

Test Connection:

"Connected to mailbox. 
Searching folder...
Found matching email(s) : 1. 
Result: Success!"

I have test "Poll SCM" and "Build periodically" it are work fine .

Jenkins ver. 1.614

poll-mailbox-trigger ver. 0.16

in schedule : H/5 * * * *

Comment: Hi Ali, I noticed you closed the issue - https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29234 . Did you resolve the issue by restarting Jenkins?

Comment: @NickGrealy yeah, after restart Jenkins it works fine.
sorry I completely forget about this post. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After configuring the plugin details .Just enable the auto refresh option at the top . So its not required to restart the jenkins any time.